# Why is the verb conjugated to え-form?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, conjugations, word-usage

> 選べなかったら俺ん家来れば？

Translation:
If you don't like your choices, why not live at my place?

What I'm particularly confused about is the verb being in え-form. As far as I know, one usage of it is to give commands (imperative), but if that's the case I don't get why it's used here.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Now that it's clearer that you're asking about the 選べ rather than the 来れば, ignore the next paragraph and skip to the end.

While え-form can indeed imply imperative, if it's ～えば then that's a provisional ("if") form, i.e. it means "If you came to my place ..." and in this context it's probably been contracted from 来ればいい, which is used to offer a suggestion. Sort of like "Wouldn't it be good if you ...?" or "You could always ...".

The 選べ is *not* an imperative え-form. It is, in fact, part of a conditional negative potential form. Specifically:

選ぶ　(choose) →　選べる　(can choose) →　選べない　(can't choose) →　選べなかったら (if [you] can't choose)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I'm sorry I didn't make myself clear here, since I forgot that "来れば" is also in え-form, but I meant to ask about the "選べ" at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: Ah, that's a different conjugation entirely. I thought you might have misinterpreted that one too since your translation was slightly off.